# php - got no $_POST values with multipart/form-data

Tags: java, apache, http, post, multipartform-data

The question is easy. I am requesting:

```
POST /api/?user=auth HTTP/1.1 Content-Length: 437 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg; charset=UTF-8 Host: 192.168.0.10:8888 Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

--tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

KJjhyuJHYsadfU78
--tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_login"

9053494481
--tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_password"

8013468v30
--tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_terms"

no
--tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg--
```

and receive $_POST === array() in PHP.

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 03:29:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2004-2012 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
```

And

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

Checked the server for rewrite redirects that can lose data - found none.
Please, help.

**RESOLVED**: I used apache library to send multipart request. It produced header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg; charset=UTF-8
```

When I remove encoding settings, it changed to:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg
```

And now all works smooth.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_REQUEST);`. What does it output? `$_REQUEST` should fetch both `$_GET` and `$_POST` data.

Comment: I did that. $_GET returns what expected, "user" index with "auth" value. $_POST array is empty, as I wrote. $_REQUEST contains same data as $_GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**: I used apache library to send multipart request. It produced header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg; charset=UTF-8
```

When I remove encoding settings, it changed to:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=tYhL_Uv6shSE9A9DHwvtJvXb0NPSLNMsdg
```

And now all works smooth.

Answer (score 0):

That is a GET method!

Use:

```
$_GET
```